# How to search my DB for specific m to n relations saved in a jointable

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using a postgreSQL DB on my Rails app. I have established m-to-n relationships between `Slots` and `Hashtags`. The last thing I need is to find `Slots` who match specific `Hashtags` given per `url params`

Here is the schema.rb

```
  create_table "hashtags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "value"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "hashtags_slots", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "hashtag_id", null: false
    t.bigint "slot_id", null: false
    t.index ["hashtag_id"], name: "index_hashtags_slots_on_hashtag_id"
    t.index ["slot_id"], name: "index_hashtags_slots_on_slot_id"
  end

  create_table "slots", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "slot_name"
    t.string "file_path"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["slot_name"], name: "index_slots_on_slot_name"
  end
```

I want to show the Index of the slots filled with `slots` who have one of the hashtags that is given through the `params[:hashtags]`. The value of Hashtags can contain 1 or more Strings like so:

```
hashtags = "NetEnt PlayNGo Novomatic"
```

This is inside the `index` action of the `Slot` controller

```
if(params[:slot_name])
      @slots = Slot.where(slot_name: params[:slot_name]).paginate(page: params[:page])
    elsif(params[:hashtags])
      @slots = slotsWithAtLeastOneOfThose(params[:hashtags])
    else
      @slots = Slot.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
```

How should a method

```
slotsWithAtLeastOneOfThose(hashtags)
  slots = ...
  return slots
end
```

look like to give me all the `Slots`that have at least one `hashtag` in the `hashtags` variable

Consider those relations:

**Slot table**:

```
 id: 1 slot_name: Book of Dead
 id: 2 slot_name: Big Win Cat
 id: 3 slot_name: Big Bad Wolf
```

**Hashtag table:**

```
 id: 1 value: PlayNGo
 id: 2 value: Fun
 id: 3 value: NetEnt
 id: 4 value: MicroGaming
 id: 5 value: NotFun
```

**Hashtags_Slots table** would look like this:

```
slot_id            hashtag_id
1                  1
1                  2
2                  2
2                  3
2                  5
3                  4
3                  5
```

And now the method

```
slotsWithAtLeastOneOfThose("PlayNGo NetEnt")
```

should give me all the `Slots` with the Hashtag `PlayNGo` and `NetEnt`

In this case

```
 id: 1 slot_name: Book of Dead
 id: 2 slot_name: Big Win Cat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below query for getting slots with particular hash tag value

```
if(params[:slot_name])
   @slots = Slot.where(slot_name: params[:slot_name]).paginate(page: params[:page])
elsif(params[:hashtags])
   @slots = Slot.joins(:hashtags).where("hashtags.value LIKE ?", "%#{params[:hashtags]}%")
else
   @slots = Slot.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Comment: `irb(main):062:0> Slot.joins(hashtags_slots: :hashtags).where("hashtags.value LIKE ?", "NetEnt")
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Slot' to association named 'hashtags_slots'; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: Yes, definitely i misspelled it. can you please add association of model in question ?

Comment: still the same. I have something like this that gives me the slots that have a hashtag : `Slot.joins(:hashtags)` I just need the right `where` clause to filter after the hashtag values

Comment: Updated answer, please check , also please add  associations  in question. so i can better understand

Comment: yeah I just found the same solution, I mark yours right as this is the right one.  The associations are all clear in my question: you have the schema and I gave a big example

Comment: You can also upvote it, so it will help other users in future